# Statistics on common readings for Japanese names

Tags: names, gender, statistics

I am looking for statistics (raw data) on the most common readings for kanji used in names (family name or first name) and the most common gender for a name. Existing dictionaries tend to just spit out all possible readings for a name even when only 1 or 2 are likely; I'd like to improve that.

There are loads of websites that offer this on a per-lookup basis, e.g. https://namegen.jp/yomikata - so the raw data must be out there. I checked Census data but could not find it. I googled for research papers and visited websites. http://www.myj7000.jp-biz.net/1000/0100f.htm looked promising, but is broken? Or I can't figure out how to use it.

I have searched for combinations like 名字調査 統計 データ etc. but to no avail. Would really appreciate any help.

I also considered crawling wikipedia, which would work (if I can figure out how to remove fictional characters) but won't be as granular or accurate as the data these other sites are using.

Answer (score 2):

The website you gave gives stats:

example for 雅

https://namegen.jp/yomikata?name=%E9%9B%85

This looks like exactly what you want

Comment: そのサイト、女性の名前のところに、「まさ」がないんですねえ。「[雅]{まさ}子」って、「[雅]{みや(び)}」の付く名前より多そうなのに。 **Edit:** あっ、「雅」１文字の名前の統計なのね。「雅子」「雅美」とかは除外されてる。

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for raw data. Amended my question to reflect that :)

Comment: @Chocolate 一字だけを入力してその字が入っている名前のランキング見てみたいものだね。データ自体は合ってると思う？「雅子」のページを参考すると「みやこ」より「まさこ」の方がずっと多いというデータが書いてあったし。

Comment: そうですね、その字が入ってるいろんな名前のランキングがあればいいですよね。　データの信頼度については、「S（非常に信頼できる）」「A（かなり信頼できる）」「E（あまり信頼できない）」とか書いてありますね～（誰が評価してるんでしょうね～）SとかAとかのところは「ああ、確かに～そうだろうな～」って気はしますね～

Comment: 信頼度はおそらくヒット数（人口数）によって付けられているだろう。問題はどうやってあのデータを手に入れたんだろう…国勢調査だと思ったけど調べたところで見つからないんだ…